# Fixed Frame [map] does not exist

Tags: ros, rviz, fixed-frame, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm asking this question after going through almost every thread with similar questions, but still unable to solve this issue. I'll elaborate all steps I'm doing to make it easy for troubleshooting.

I'm trying to run [this package](https://github.com/sourishg/stereo-dense-reconstruction). I'm using two Logitech C270 USB cameras and the `usb_cam` package. The `launch` file looks like this:

```
<launch>
  <group ns="camera1">
    <node name="usb_cam1" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
        <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />
        <param name="image_width" value="640" />
        <param name="image_height" value="480" />
        <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
        <param name="camera_frame_id" value="yuyv" />
        <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
    </node>
    <node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
       <remap from="image" to="/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw"/>
       <param name="autosize" value="true" />
    </node>
  </group>

  <group ns="camera2">
    <node name="usb_cam2" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
      <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video1" />
      <param name="image_width" value="640" />
      <param name="image_height" value="480" />
      <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
      <param name="camera_frame_id" value="yuyv" />
     <param name="io_method" value="mmap"/>
   </node>
   <node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
     <remap from="image" to="/camera2/usb_cam2/image_raw"/>
     <param name="autosize" value="true" />
   </node>
  </group>
</launch>
```

Cameras are grabbing images and there's no issue. If I do a `rostopic list` I get these topics:

```
/camera1/image_view/output
/camera1/image_view/parameter_descriptions
/camera1/image_view/parameter_updates
/camera1/usb_cam1/camera_info
/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw
/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw/compressed
/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw/theora
/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera1/usb_cam1/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera2/image_view/output
/camera2/image_view/parameter_descriptions
/camera2/image_view/parameter_updates
/camera2/usb_cam2/camera_info
/camera2/usb_cam2/image_raw
/camera2/usb_cam2/image_raw/compressed
/camera2/usb_cam2/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera2/usb_cam2/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera2/usb_cam2/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera2/usb_cam2/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera2/usb_cam2/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera2/usb_cam2/image_raw/theora
/camera2/usb_cam2/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera2/usb_cam2/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

Now I run the nodes as described in the `README` file [here](https://github.com/sourishg/stereo-dense-reconstruction/blob/master/README.md). When I run `rviz` , I get these

```
No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist
```

So I used `gmapping` as pointed out [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/195962/rviz-fixed-frame-world-does-not-exist/)

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping
```

this time I do get `Global Status: Ok` `Fixed Frame: Ok` .

Now I can add a new display of the topic `/camera_left_rect/disparity_map` and disparity map is [shown](https://imgur.com/eQ65JhP) without any problem.

But if I add a new display of the topic `/camera_left_rect/point_cloud` (where point cloud is the output) I get this error:

```
Transform [sender=unknown_publisher] For frame [jackal]: Frame [jackal] does not exist
```

I did `rosrun tf view_frames` and the output is [this](https://imgur.com/7skFKxp).

Where am I doing wrong? Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263715/fixed-frame-%5Bmap%5D-does-not-exist/) by [OneLeggedPirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/30738/oneleggedpirate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-06-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-13**:
Could you please attach your `view_frames` sshot to this post directly? I've given you enough karma to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As is apparent from your `view_frames` output, you are not running any TF broadcaster.

RViz needs at least one TF authority in order to be able to transform incoming msgs such as pointclouds and other things that have a position in 3D space (ie: the visualiser window) into its scene graph properly.

You configure the root of the transformation tree that RViz is supposed to use with the `Fixed Frame` setting, which in your case if set to `map`. But without anyone publishing a transform from `map` to whatever `frame_id` is configured in the incoming msgs that is not going to work.

Two options:

1. add a `static_tf_publisher` to your launch file that sets up a proper TF tree for all frames involved
2. change the `Fixed Frame` setting to correspond to any of the frames that are used by any of the incoming msgs (just select the field and *type* the name of the frame in the textbox)

The proper approach would be 1, but to quickly visualise something, 2 would work.

---

Edit: and unless you actually *want* to do some robot localisation and / or map building, I would not bother with `gmapping` (or any of the related pkgs).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OneLeggedPirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/30738/oneleggedpirate/) on 2017-06-13**:
For option 1, how do I add a `static_tf_publisher` ?

P.S: If I do not use `gmapping`, I get `No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist` . In this case, `view_frames` returns `no tf data received`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-13**:
It would probably be good if you could provide us with a bit more context. Right now it's a unclear whether you are trying to create a static setup (ie: two webcams with a computer on your desk), or whether you are trying to configure a mobile robot base. The former doesn't need gmapping ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-13**:
.., for the latter it might make sense, but only if you're creating a map. Otherwise I'd use a localisation package.

But just to reiterate: `gmapping` is not a requirement for getting a TF tree setup.

**Comment by [OneLeggedPirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/30738/oneleggedpirate/) on 2017-06-13**:
I'm just using a static setup at the moment.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-14**:
Ok. Then adding a TF tree isn't that difficulty. No need for `gmapping`. Either create a urdf that describes how you've setup things (ie: relative position of the two cameras, etc), or take a look at [wiki/tf - static_transform_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher).

**Comment by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on 2017-09-16**:
I am also doing the same thing. I have 2 webcameras connected to my pc and later I want to mount them on a small rover which will navigate based on the disparity/depth map image. However I am stuck at tf broadcaster issue. Can you elaborate on how to solve the issue??@OneLeggedPirate

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2018-03-26**:
e.g. if your robot base tf is `/base_link` and your `/camera_left_rect/point_cloud` topic has *frame_id:cam_left_ptcloud* you need something like

`rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0.0 0.0 0.0  0 0 0 /base_link cam_left_ptcloud 100`

; that static tf node then acts as the 'tf authority' .

**Comment by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) on 2018-03-26**:
... e.g. https://answers.ros.org/question/221329/rviz-fixed-frame-map-does-not-exist/?answer=221357

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

these helped me

```
sudo apt install ros-humble-gazebo-ros
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-gazebo-msgs
sudo apt-get install ros-humble-gazebo-plugins
```

---

Originally posted by [bharath5673](https://answers.ros.org/users/135625/bharath5673/) with karma: 11 on 2023-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1